# about managing file system space

Tags: linux, filesystems, alert

Space Issues in a filesystem on Linux
Lets call it FILESYSTEM1
Normally, space in FILESYSTEM1 is only about 40-50% used

and clients run some reports or run some queries and these reports produce massive files about 4-5GB in size and this instantly fills up FILESYSTEM1.

We have some cleanup scripts in place but they never catch this because it happens in a matter of minutes and the cleanup scripts usually clean data that is more than 5-7 days old.

Another set of scripts are also in place and these report when free space in a filesystem is less than a certain threshold

we thought of possible solutions to detect and act on this proactively.

1. Increase the FILESYSTEM1 file system to double its size.
2. set the threshold in the Alert Scripts for this filesystem to alert when 50% full.
3. This will hopefully give us enough time to catch this and act before the client reports issues due to FILESYSTEM1 being full.

Even though this solution works, does not seem to be the best way to deal with the situation.

Any suggestions / comments / solutions are welcome.

thanks

Comment: Quotas aren't a solution why?

Comment: when you say quotas, what are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you've found is that simple threshold-based monitoring doesn't work well for the usage patterns you're dealing with. I'd suggest something that pairs high-frequency sampling (say, once a minute) with a monitoring tool that can do some kind of regression on your data to predict when space will run out.

In addition to knowing when you've already run out of space, you also need to know whether you're about to run out of space. Several tools can do this, or you can write your own. One existing tool is Zabbix, which has [predictive trigger functions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/triggers/prediction) that can be used to alert when file system usage seems likely to cross a threshold within a certain period of time. This may be useful in reacting to rapid changes that, left unchecked, would fill the file system.

Comment: Hi charley,  We have some in-house scripts which alert when we are running out of space and also at certain thresholds.  The predictive trigger functions in Zabbix will pretty do the same thing that we are implementing with the in-house scripts they are more mathematical in approach. Will do more reading on Zabbix to see if those features may provide a slightly more robust way to deal with the problem at hand.

Comment: It's not a specific recommendation for Zabbix. That's just an example that came to mind.